# Hierarchical linear regression

Tags: r, regression, self-study, multiple-regression

This is more a self-study question I think.

From what I know, a hierarchical linear regression is when you build a model and from there you start creating new models adding a new variable on each new model untill you get to the full model. After that you compare if each model has improved the fit or not observing the R². Then, in the last step, you do an analysis of variance to see which model is "significant" different.

What is the difference of creating a bunch of models and doing a direct anova on the full model? Is it only to observe the amount of variance changed through models using the R² parameter?

Another question I have: is there another nomenclature to refer to this type of analysis? Since it can be misundertood as hierarchical modeling... would it be regression models comparison?

**Edit 1:** the question arose from this [blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-hierarchical-linear-regression/)

And as pointed out by the people in the comments, the nomenclature "HLR" given by the author's post is actually a forward selection method of regression

Comment: I think you are thinking of stepwise regression, hierarchical regression is where your samples are organised at two or more levels...eg repeated measurements of subjects, schools and students, ...

Comment: Stepwise regression is when you drop off variables to find the best model, right? But my question came out after I read this post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-hierarchical-linear-regression/

Comment: That author's "HLR" sure sounds like a hand-rolled forward stepwise regression.  He never explains or defines what he means by HLR and he doesn't address crucial issues like adjusting for multiple comparisons.  Stepwise regression is treated in detail in just about any multiple regression textbook originally published between 1980 and 2005 (including any more recent editions--somehow textbooks only accumulate material; they almost never delete it).

Comment: So in general, the best course of action is to use a full model with all predictors (based on your theoretical approach) instead of building up different models with forward selection? And this R² comparison between models doesn't make much sense, right? (and multiple models add the multiple comparisons problem whuber cited)

Comment: It's complicated.  You can read about the issues by searching our site for keywords like "model selection" and "variable identification" as well as "lasso" and "glmnet."  I believe a case can be made for judicious use of stepwise evaluation of nested models ("HLR"), *especially* when those models have been suggested beforehand by theoretical considerations or previous studies. (Others categorically declare all stepwise methods to be bad, so YMMV.)  The $R^2$ comparison can make sense provided it is done appropriately--but comparing related statistics, such as AIC, tends to be more reliable.